# Is there anyway to let Android auto install apk from SD card?(like autorun.inf in windows,not apps)

Tags: android, installation

I want to let Android auto install apk from SD card,(like autorun.inf in windows).I can do something like programing on sdcard,but not the Android Phones.
PS:I needn't let the installation background as I know it needs root,but I want to the installation of apk starts.

Comment: I hope you'll get the answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);

Comment: @Sushil  In fact,I think that question means install apk using installed application,but now I can't install any app on the phone,only the sd Card

Comment: Ohh.. okay. I understand your question now..

Comment: I dont think it whould be possible then..

Comment: Thank you very much.I know it's hard to achieve,but I want to have a try.Maybe like virus

Comment: Will wait for you post an answer if you can achieve this :). It would be an useful Virus :) :)